# Excel formula returning a blank space

Tags: excel

[image]

So I want to search for the values in *column C*, but when I press **Enter** after writting the formula it return a *blank cell*, if I format it with F9 though it returns the right value.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$994;SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3;$B$3:$B$994))*
(SEARCH($H$3;$D$3:$D$994)));ROW($D$3:$D$994)-MIN(ROW($D$3:$D$994))+1;"");ROW(A1)));"")
```

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array formula so needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

F9 also forces the formula to be evaluated as an array formula so that's why you get the correct result: otherwise the IFERROR statement in the outside pair of brackets will come into play and result in a blank cell.

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about that.